# how can I logout from a openstack user

Tags: openstack

how can I logout from a openstack  user  to which I have switched using the RC file with out closing the terminal. I hav tried the "exit" command but it closes the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

The RC script **exports** environment variables related to authentication.

If you wish to not be authenticated anymore you could **unset** these variables, or source a different RC file in order to switch users.

Essentially the minimal contents of an RC file are the following:

```
export OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_NAME=...
export OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME=...
export OS_PROJECT_NAME=...
export OS_USERNAME=...
export OS_PASSWORD=...    
export OS_AUTH_URL=...
```

You could create and source a script with the following content to in order to `logout`:

```
unset OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_NAME
unset OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME
unset OS_PROJECT_NAME
unset OS_USERNAME
unset OS_PASSWORD    
unset OS_AUTH_URL
```

If there are more environment variables in your RC file, related to authentication you can add them too.

Comment: so a logout-rc file (namely) with all the unset command will help me to logout by using the #source logout-rc

Comment: That's right. In this way the environment variables will be unset and you will not be authorized to use the OpenStack services. Alternatively, you could switch users by sourcing another RC script, if this works for you.

Comment: While using the new rc file using all the unset commands, the terminal prompts "Not a valid Identifier"

Comment: Rather than *unset*, you can try *declare +x*. This removes a variable from the export list.

Comment: @DdevilPrasad I don't know what could be wrong without seeing the content of your file. I just tried this again and the environment variables are indeed unset without any error.